# Iterating over array with string

Tags: d

```
import std.stdio, std.string, std.conv, std.array;
int main(){
foreach(int i,s; splitter("Hello world !")){
    writeln(i);
    };
    return 0;
}
```

Hello everyone!
I want get get string index in array and string.
Why I get this error ?

```
dmd main.d
Error: cannot infer argument types
make: *** [c] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of the range model: foreach over ranges gives a current item, but not a current index. The easiest fixes would be to use split from std.string/std.array (which eagerly allocates a new array to hold the result and returns that) or to simply keep a count yourself in an outside variable:

```
int i;
foreach(s; splitter("whatever")) {
   // use s and i
   i++;
}
```

Though note that the range returned from splitter cannot be indexed anyway... `splitter("whatever")[0]` won't compile. The way splitter works is it finds the next split point only on demand, and it can only do that one at a time since it involves scanning the string. Ranges as a general rule don't like to use loops inside their methods - so the speed complexity is easily visible to the user - and scanning the string of course needs a loop.

The index could perhaps be kept automatically, but the language simply doesn't do it. With some custom foreach operations, it calls a function you define:

```
int opApply(int delegate(int idx, string s) dg);
```

There, you could `foreach(i, s) {}` and it would figure it out from the opApply definition. But with ranges, it does this:

```
for(auto f = range.front; !range.empty; range.popFront())
```

With no room for the range to define a second index variable, and no automatic insertion. This could perhaps change at some point, but how exactly it would go is up in the air and there's no particular rush to do it in the community - adding your own int counter variable is easy enough that this limitation isn't much of a showstopper, though it annoys a few of us at times.

Answer (score 2):

In future(https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/pull/1866) you will be able to use this code:

```
import std.range: enumerate;

foreach(i, s; splitter("Hello world !").enumerate){
    writeln(i);
}
```